# Object mapping with deep nesting

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object:

```
const object = {
  children: [{
    uuid: '1',
    children: [{
        uuid: '2',
        children: [{
            uuid: '3',
            children: []
          },
          {
            uuid: '4',
            children: [{
              uuid: '5',
              children: []
            }]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        uuid: '6',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

I need a function that will map each child:

Javascript

```
deepMapChildren(object, (child) => ({...child, uuid: 'new uuid'}))
```

Does anyone have a script for this or know of a built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution calls `deepMapChildren` recursively on the each child to update the child, and it's children. The function uses destructuring with rest to separate the `children` from the current child. It then spreads the results of applying the callback `cb` to the child, and mapping the children with `deepMapChildren`.

```js
const deepMapChildren = (obj, cb, childrenKey = 'children') => {
  const { [childrenKey]: children = [], ...child } = cb(obj); // update the child, and seperate the child's content and it's children
  
  return {
    ...child,
    [childrenKey]: children.map(c => deepMapChildren(c, cb)) // map the children (if any)
  };
}

const object = {"children":[{"uuid":"1","children":[{"uuid":"2","children":[{"uuid":"3","children":[]},{"uuid":"4","children":[{"uuid":"5","children":[]}]}]},{"uuid":"6","children":[]}]}]}

const result = deepMapChildren(object, (child) => 
  ({...child, uuid: 'new uuid'})
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution, but it does not work for all cases.

Comment: You are welcome. It's hard to design something for all cases, without knowing the cases. Were does it fail?

Comment: deepMapChildren(state, (node) => { if (node.uuid === parentId) { return { ...node, children: [...node.children, newElement], }; } return node; });  node.children is undefined

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work when I push new children inside callback: deepMapChildren(state, (node) => { if (node.uuid === parentId) { return { ...node, children: [...node.children, newElement], }; } return node; })

Comment: You need to check if the node has children before you try to manipulate it -  `if (node.uuid === parentId && node.children)`

Comment: 'Children' sometimes can be an empty array, but it must always have been. Please check it https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rjjvxw